# Засунуть переменную Date в сложный SQlite запрос и высчитать разницу

Tags: sqlite

```
SELECT 
    CAST((strftime('%s', 'now','localtime') - strftime('%s', '2011-11-09 09:00'))/(60 * 60 * 24) AS TEXT) || ' ' || 
    CAST(((strftime('%s', 'now','localtime') - strftime('%s', '2011-11-09 09:00')) % (60 * 60 * 24))/(60 * 60) AS TEXT) || ':' || 
    CAST((((strftime('%s', 'now','localtime') - strftime('%s', '2011-11-09 09:00')) % (60 * 60 * 24)) % (60 * 60))/60 AS TEXT);
```

в этот код  на место второго времени нужно каким то образом поставить значени из таблицы

```
select date from users where userId=123421
```

выводится в формате `дни минуты:часы`
может кто то сталкивался с подобным

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    CAST((strftime('%s', 'now','localtime') - strftime('%s', /* '2011-11-09 09:00' */ users.date))/(60 * 60 * 24) AS TEXT) || ' ' || 
    CAST(((strftime('%s', 'now','localtime') - strftime('%s', /* '2011-11-09 09:00' */ users.date)) % (60 * 60 * 24))/(60 * 60) AS TEXT) || ':' || 
    CAST((((strftime('%s', 'now','localtime') - strftime('%s', /* '2011-11-09 09:00' */ users.date)) % (60 * 60 * 24)) % (60 * 60))/60 AS TEXT)
from users where userId=123421 ;
```

Comment: огромное спасибо Akina ,все отлично заработало